# Jquery - Show a div after animation completed

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, show

How to show a div after that animation is completed?

This is my code, animation works but div doesn't appear…

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {                        
  $('#container-single article').delay(2000).animate(
  {left: '-490'},
  {duration: 250,
   easing: 'easeOutQuad'
   } , function() {
   $('#close').css("display", "block");
  });
});
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: also, ensure that your initial display property is indeed `none` and that youre not perhaps using `visibility:hidden`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it could be a problem with an external force like your CSS or HTML markup Ive written this.

http://jsfiddle.net/zQWa8/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {                        
  $('#container-single article').delay(2000).animate({
      left: '-490',
      easing: 'easeOutQuad'
  }, 500, function() {
      $('#close').css("display", "block");
  });
});
```